# Right to left GridView For Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, gridview

I'm Trying to find a Grid View for my new project in Asp.net MVC...I have encountered some articles in this site about it however I'd like this grid views have some special features, for example I want columns to be right to left and support Persian search (if it's possible..this feature is not as important as the first feature to me) also have column sort and paging

is there a grid view that have these features?

Comment: I heard of teleric and it's brilliant features however I have to pay a lot to use it and I don't need all of the features it gots....does it offer a free simpler grid view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JqGrid. It is based on Jquery (not specific only to MVC). It has searching, sorting, customization and culture specific features. And it is FREE.

Check it [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) and [here for RTL demo](http://www.trirand.com/blog/phpjqgrid/examples/functionality/righttoleft/default.php).

Plenty of help is available on how to use it.

Comment: it looks really useful...but since I haven't used it yet I have to ask ...if I enter data in Persian, would the column sort still work?

Comment: Since I never worked with Persian text, so can't tell if default sorting works with it or not. But you can write your own custom sort function. See the documentation for 'sorttype' property. JqGrid has extensive help and documentation available online. I have found everything I ever needed for JqGrid on stackoverflow.

Comment: I wanted to say I used it in Dreamweaver to check and it works perfectly...now I just have to translate all it's features to persian

Comment: how can i download this grid library and use it.

Comment: @Loai see this link https://jquery.com/download/.There are a lot options to suit your need.  If you work on VS you can use Nuget packagemanager  as well.